# How to convert this elasticsearch query from 2.x to 5.x index?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Our system upgraded elasticsearch from 2.x to 5.x.
Now query's are not working in 5.x written in 2.x.
So I have to convert elasticsearch query from 2.x to 5.x index?

Please suggest how to convert this query to elasticsearch 5.x query?
_score field will not be affected and able to cache this query.

```
{
  "size": 12,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "pageType": "ulp_comb"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "date": {
                  "gte": "2017-09"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "entityId": 0
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change `filtered` to `bool`

```
{
  "size": 12,
  "query": {
    "bool": { // change to bool
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "pageType": "ulp_comb"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "date": {
                  "gte": "2017-09"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "entityId": 0
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This syntax is also working in 2.x. How this is possible?

Comment: yes, it works too for 2.x. Based on doc, `filtered` is deprecated in 2.x and it is suggested to start using `bool` as replacement https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-filtered-query.html